# Android studio 3 работа офлайн gradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Не могу собрать проект при работе офлайн. Gradle скачан версия 5.3, путь в студии указан, использовать локально указано. Что и где нужно прописать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по документации вам нужно:

1. Откройте окно настроек, нажав «Файл»> «Настройки» (на Mac, Android Studio> «Настройки»).
2. На левой панели выберите Построение, Выполнение, Развертывание> Gradle.
3. Установите флажок Автономная работа.
4. Нажмите Применить или ОК.

[Вот](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build#offline_mode) документация, [здесь](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build) так же указаны и другие приемы для работы с Gradle.

Comment: Галочка о автономной работе поставлена: offline work, ошибка:no cashed vetsion of com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.3, available for offline mode

Comment: Онлайн он работает, вопрос в том чтобы он работал офлайн, gradle скачан путь указан, он не может работать без интернета?

Comment: Тогда он пишет dont conect, потому что интернета нет

Comment: Поставил галочку auto detect proxy, поставил галочку offline work. Ошибка: no cashed version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.3 available for offline mode

Comment: а путь какой? у меня для оффлайна тут хранится - `"c:\Program File\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2respository\com\android`

Comment: о, и кстати может это проблема самого градла, вернее его версии, попробуйте опустить версию или поднять, и сделать все тоже самое, ну чтобы интернет был и скачались файлы, я тут читаю что такое встречается когда версия градла неправильная

Comment: В онлайн всё собралось, в офлайн не получается. Буду пробовать варианты

Comment: можно конечно попробовать переустановить AS но чет мне кажется что это так себе вариант))

Comment: Мне тоже это как то не вариант))), хотелось настроить работу полностью автономно без интернета, не получается, буду собирать с интернетом

Comment: ну вообще работать в as без сети довольно проблематично всегда, лучше когда есть какой никакой интернет))