# Ошибка "Plugin was not found" при медленном интернете

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle

Решил создать иконку для своего приложения. Для создания иконки требовался SDK 26, а у меня был установлен API 8: Android 2.2 для большего охвата.

При запуске эмулятора начала высвечивается проблема: **Read timed out**. Новые проекты эмулируются только первый раз, а далее - та же ошибка **Read timed out** - это  запись из лога: **Gradle build failed with 1 error(s)**.

Чтобы обновить все, что связано **Gradle**, я снес старую версию AS Dolphin и установил последнюю версию 2023 года AS Flamingo. С трудом загрузил AS Flamingo торрентом - доступ к Интернету часто прерывался. Интернет у меня - плохой.

Установил эмулятор. После  установки AS Flamingo его не было (No Device).

Прокси-сервер в Android Studio не настроен. Настраивал прокси  в Android Studio, но эффекта не было. Сейчас прокси отключен.

Сейчас ошибка:
**Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.0.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources** [image: Не найден плагин]

```
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.0.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.0.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.0.0')
 Searched in the following repositories:
   Google
   MavenRepo
   Gradle Central Plugin Repository
   at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.resolveToFoundResult(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:237)
   at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.lambda$resolvePluginRequests$3(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:167)
   at org.gradle.util.internal.CollectionUtils.collect(CollectionUtils.java:212)
   at org.gradle.util.internal.CollectionUtils.collect(CollectionUtils.java:206)
   at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.resolvePluginRequests(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:165)
   at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:100)
   at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:117)
   at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
   at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
   at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:44)
   at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:388)
   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:406)
   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:387)
   at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:42)
   at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
   at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:35)
   at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:109)
   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:388)
   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$fromMutableState$1(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:411)
   at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withReplacedLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:345)
   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:411)
   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:387)
   at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:100)
   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
   at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:72)
   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:792)
   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:156)
   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectLifecycleController.lambda$ensureSelfConfigured$2(ProjectLifecycleController.java:84)
   at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$13(StateTransitionController.java:247)
   at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:258)
   at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:246)
   at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$maybeTransitionIfNotCurrentlyTransitioning$10(StateTransitionController.java:207)
   at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:34)
   at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.maybeTransitionIfNotCurrentlyTransitioning(StateTransitionController.java:203)
   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectLifecycleController.ensureSelfConfigured(ProjectLifecycleController.java:84)
   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.ensureConfigured(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:362)
   at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:33)
   at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
   at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(DefaultProjectsPreparer.java:42)
   at org.gradle.configuration.BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.java:64)
   at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer$ConfigureBuild.run(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:52)
   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
   at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:40)
   at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.lambda$prepareProjects$2(VintageBuildModelController.java:84)
   at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$13(StateTransitionController.java:247)
   at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:258)
   at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:246)
   at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transitionIfNotPreviously$11(StateTransitionController.java:221)
   at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:34)
   at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transitionIfNotPreviously(StateTransitionController.java:217)
   at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.prepareProjects(VintageBuildModelController.java:84)
   at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.getConfiguredModel(VintageBuildModelController.java:64)
   at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$withProjectsConfigured$1(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:116)
   at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$notInState$4(StateTransitionController.java:154)
   at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
   at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.notInState(StateTransitionController.java:150)
   at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.withProjectsConfigured(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:116)
   at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildToolingModelController.locateBuilderForTarget(DefaultBuildToolingModelController.java:57)
   at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator$DefaultBuildTreeModelController.lambda$locateBuilderForTarget$0(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:73)
   at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.withToolingModels(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:185)
   at org.gradle.internal.build.AbstractBuildState.withToolingModels(AbstractBuildState.java:134)
   at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator$DefaultBuildTreeModelController.locateBuilderForTarget(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:73)
   at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator$DefaultBuildTreeModelController.locateBuilderForDefaultTarget(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:68)
   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getTarget(DefaultBuildController.java:157)
   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getModel(DefaultBuildController.java:101)
   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(ParameterAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:39)
   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.getModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:113)
   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.findModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:97)
   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.findModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.findModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:81)
   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.findModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.findModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:66)
   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.findModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
   at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:125)
   at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:42)
   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:64)
   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.runAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:131)
   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.beforeTasks(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:99)
   at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.beforeTasks(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:52)
   at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$fromBuildModel$2(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:74)
   at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$runBuild$4(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:98)
   at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$6(StateTransitionController.java:177)
   at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:258)
   at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$7(StateTransitionController.java:177)
   at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
   at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transition(StateTransitionController.java:177)
   at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:95)
   at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.fromBuildModel(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:73)
   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.runClientAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:43)
   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:53)
   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
   at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:49)
   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:65)
   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:140)
   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
   at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:122)
   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
   at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
   at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
   at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
   at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.continuous.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:110)
   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
   at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:100)
   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:88)
   at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:69)
   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:63)
   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:50)
   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:38)
   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
   at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
   at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:64)
   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
```

**build.gradle**:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.mypp08052'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mypp08052"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.3.2'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.1'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'
}
```

**settings.gradle**:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "My Pp08052"
include ':app'
```

**gradle wrapper**:

```
#Mon May 08 15:19:32 EEST 2023
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему с установкой плагина.

Comment: ошибка не относится к SDK. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605734/android-studio-gradle-build-error-read-time-out

Comment: Попробовал первые три самые популярные решения по вашему линку - проблему не решил..

Comment: во-первых добавьте в вопрос свои градл файлы, во-вторых уточните есть ли у вас использование каких-то прокси? вот проблема как здесь описана - https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3636, и вот есть конфиг для прокси - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy

Comment: buil.gradle нужно прикрепить

Comment: Пытаюсь прикрепить buil.gradle по следующей инструкции: 1. Откройте проект в Android Studio.
2. В окне "Project" найдите файл "build.gradle" в разделе "app".
3. Щелкните правой кнопкой мыши на файл "build.gradle" и выберите "Open as Project Settings" (Открыть как настройки проекта).
4. В открывшемся диалоговом окне вы можете изменять настройки проекта, включая версию SDK, настройки Gradle и другие параметры.
5. После внесения изменений нажмите "Apply" (Применить), чтобы сохранить настройки проекта.  Но у меня нет "Open as Project Settings".  Скрин - в вопросе. Что делать? @Andrew

Comment: нужно открыть файл build.gradle -> ctrl+a -> ctrl+c -> перейти в редактирование вопрос -> ctrl+v. Картинки удалить после этого.

Comment: Открываю build.gradle. Команда ctrl+a выделяет содержимое/код файла (синий цвет).  Команда  ctrl+c, наверное, копирует выделенное. Что редактировать? Где редактировать? Возможно подскажете какую строку надо вписать\изменть в коде, чтобы привязать build.gradle. @Andrew

Comment: как вы картинки добавляли/удаляли? кнопка "Править" под вашим вопросом

Comment: Да я не о картинках и кнопках сайта ru.stackoverflow.com. Мне надо прикрепить к проекту build.gradle в  Андроид Студио! @Andrew

Comment: Что-то я ничего уже не понял, у вас этот файл генерится автоматически с новым проектом. Вы его удалили что ли?

Comment: Я ничего не удалял При компиляции высвечивается  - Download gradle 8.0.zip @Andrew

Comment: И  еще. Установил эмулятор, раньше было No Device. Эмулятор на запускается через проблему Read timed out.  Как в этом случае увеличить время таймаута? @Andrew

Comment: переустановите студию, может установка побилась, вместе с градлом и тп, у вас эмулятор не может подцепится

Comment: В эмуляторе я уверен - он воспроизвел первый раз после установки проект. Я пришел к точке, с которой стартовал на сайте с вопросом. Хотелось бы побороться с низким качеством инета, увеличив время таймаута. Надеюсь на помощь. @Andrew

Comment: Приложите полный текст ошибки (вместе с полным стектрейсом). "Read timed out" и "Gradle build failed" -- эта информация не выглядит достаточной, чтобы понять, где возникла проблема и где именно нужно увеличивать таймаут. Чтобы увидеть весь текст ошибки, скорей всего нужно нажать [куда-то сюда](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0YVO.png). Скопируйте весь текст ошибки и добавтьте его в вопрос (в виде текста, а не скриншотом). Отредактировать вопрос можно по кнопке [edit] под вопросом.

Comment: Vadik Sirekanyan, спасибо, как соавтору, за внятную постановку вопроса и форматирование.  Описание ошибки "Read timed out" не могу приложить, поскольку не знаю где ее найти. Делал по инструкции с вашей картинки. Ошибки "Gradle build failed" после установки Студии 2023 уже нет.  @Vadik Sirekanyan

Comment: Для увеличения времени таймаута добавил в build.gradle  код : `        // Увеличить таймаут соединения
        android.useAndroidX=true
        android.enableJetifier=true
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
            preDexLibraries = false

            timeOutInMs 180000 

        }`   Кроме того, вписал в gradle.properties две строки: `android.adb.timeout=180000
-Dhttp.keepAlive=false -Dhttp.maxConnections=100 -Dhttps.keepAlive=false -Dhttps.maxConnections=1000 -Dhttp.socketTimeout=180000 -Dorg.gradle.internal.http.socketTimeout=180000`  Не помогло. @Vadik

Comment: Стал сомневаться, что дело в качестве интернета, ведь такой же интернет у меня был не меньше полгода  до появления проблемы. Какие еще версии ошибки "Read timed out" нужно проверить? @Vadik Sirekanyan

Comment: Создал сегодня новый проект. При его запуске - Connect timed out. Закрыл проект, снова открыл, ошибка - Read timed out. Все как на вашей картинке [https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVgwH.png], только имя проекта другое. @Vadik Sirekanyan

Comment: В вашей конфигурации нет никаких проблем. Я создал [демо-проект](https://github.com/sirekanian/q1516312), все работает исправно. Проверял командой `./gradlew clean assemble`. Плагин [com.android.application](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.0.0) существует в Google-репозитории.

Comment: Такая ошибка возникает, если у вас нет выхода в интернет. Например, я подключился к точке Wi-Fi без доступа в интернет и получил такую же ошибку. Проверьте на вашем компьютере, можете ли вы открыть эту ссылку: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/application/com.android.application.gradle.plugin/8.0.0/com.android.application.gradle.plugin-8.0.0.pom

Comment: @Cadas, не нужно менять вопрос, когда на него уже дан ответ. Я откатил изменения на две правки назад. Пожалуйста, заведите новый вопрос по новой проблеме. Все изменения этого вопроса вы можете посмотреть в [истории правок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1516312/revisions).

Comment: @Cadas, не меняйте больше ваш вопрос. Невозможно ответить на него, если в нем будет две противоречащие фразы: "интернет отличный" и "интернет у меня плохой". Раз у вас уже все хорошо с интернетом, то заведите новый вопрос для новой проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

В вашей конфигурации нет никаких проблем. Я создал [демо-проект](https://github.com/sirekanian/q1516312), все работает исправно. Проверял командой `./gradlew clean assemble`.

Плагин `com.android.application` версии 8.0.0 [находится](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.0.0) в Google-репозитории.

Однако если удалить плагин `com.android.application` из кэша Gradle (который находится в `~/.gradle/caches`) и подключиться к точке доступа Wi-Fi, у которой нет доступа в интернет, то я получаю такую же проблему:

> Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.0.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:
>
> - Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
> - Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.0.0')
>   Searched in the following repositories:
>   - Google
>   - MavenRepo
>   - Gradle Central Plugin Repository

Проверьте на вашем компьютере подключение к интернету. Для того, чтобы Gradle нашел указанный плагин, необходимо, чтобы у вас был доступ до [этого файла](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/application/com.android.application.gradle.plugin/8.0.0/com.android.application.gradle.plugin-8.0.0.pom)

Comment: ТС написал что интернет у него паршивый - в этом и есть вся проблема. Вы предлагаете проверить настройки сети - какие именно и как их нужно настроить? У меня происходит тоже самое, когда я пользуюсь мобильным интернетом, кончается пакет трафика и оператор ограничивает скорость до издевательской. Кроме как выкачивать зависимости качалкой и складывать их в локальный репозиторий с подключением `mavenLocal()` я пока ничего не придумал.

Comment: @woesss У сервера `dl.google.com` свой таймаут секунд 10 и еще, выглядит так, что он не поддерживает [докачку](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18180441) файлов. Выходит, что вариантов нет, кроме как найти хороший интернет и все скачать. 1) Либо скачать все в локальный мавен-репозиторий 2) либо скачать все в gradle-кэш и пользоваться оффлайн-режимом в IDE 3) либо настроить свое зеркало maven.

Comment: @woesss, спасибо, я поправил свой ответ, уточнил, что именно нужно проверить. Если указанный файл по каким-то причинам отдается медленно, то Gradle будет выдавать ошибку "Плагин не найден". Гипотетически такое может происходить, если недобросовестный провайдер замедлит доступ к серверу `dl.google.com` или по любой другой причине "медленного интернета".

Answer (score 0):

В Gradle [есть](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/v8.0.0/subprojects/resources-http/src/main/java/org/gradle/internal/resource/transport/http/JavaSystemPropertiesHttpTimeoutSettings.java#L28-L30) следующие системные переменные, с помощью которых можно задать timeout для сетевых запросов:

```
org.gradle.internal.http.connectionTimeout     — по-умолчанию 30 секунд
org.gradle.internal.http.socketTimeout         — по-умолчанию 30 секунд
org.gradle.internal.http.idleConnectionTimeout — по-умолчанию 3 минуты
```

Чтобы увеличить время таймаута в 10 раз, добавьте в файл `gradle.properties` следующие строчки:

```
systemProp.org.gradle.internal.http.socketTimeout=300000
systemProp.org.gradle.internal.http.connectionTimeout=300000
systemProp.org.gradle.internal.http.idleConnectionTimeout=1800000
```

Обратите внимание на префикс `systemProp.` перед именами системных переменных.

---

Тем не менее этот вариант может не сработать при очень плохом соединении, так как у сервера `dl.google.com` свой таймаут и он может разорвать соединение раньше.

Если у вас есть возможность найти хороший интернет, запустите сборку, чтобы скачать все зависимости в кэш. Далее включите [offline-режим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1005639) в Android Studio, чтобы продолжать разработку при плохом интернете.

Comment: Добавил строки, чтобы увеличить время таймаута в 10 раз. Хотя понимал, что это не решит проблемы - я это делал и раньше. Вы откатили мою редакцию вопроса, но я уже работаю в других условиях - с  ВЫСОКОСКОРОСТНЫМ интернетом. Мои уточнения вопроса ушли в никуда.  Создавать новый вопрос с той же проблемой не вижу смысла. Замкнутый круг?

Comment: В этой проблеме вы написали, что вы работаете в условиях медленного интернета. Мой ответ про то, как можно избежать указанных ошибок при работе с медленным интернетом. Всю историю правок смотрите в [истории правок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1516312/revisions). Не меняйте вопрос, я об этом вам уже писал и давал эту ссылку в комментариях под вашим вопросом. Указанная в вопросе ошибка, на которую я написал вам ответ, в условиях быстрого интернета возникать не будет. Заводите новый вопрос, раз условия и ошибки теперь другие.

Comment: С каждой ошибкой нужно разбираться отдельно. Нельзя так в одном вопросе сразу решить все ошибки, которые у вас возникают. Одна ошибка -- один вопрос. Прикладывайте в новый вопрос сразу подробный текст ошибки и его стектрейс целиком, чтобы было с чем работать по существу.