# Android Studio, ошибка: Unable to tunnel through proxy

Tags: android-studio, gradle, proxy, плагин

При перезагрузке проекта в Android Studio получаю ошибку: **Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented"**.

Wi-Fi точка подключения - это высокоскоростной Интернет со скоростью загрузки 100...200 Мбит/с моего соседа, у меня скорость Интернета на порядок ниже.

Что было сделано для устранения ошибки.
Добавил в gradle.properties код. Вместо YOUR_PROXY_SERVER_ADDRESS в коде вписывал IP-адрес в формате ххх.158.53.ххх и в формате vlххх.best.xxx, а YOUR_PROXY_PORT задавал 80. Я новичок с небольшим опытом и не знаю, как определить порт подключения. Эти действия ошибку не устранили.

Далее. Удалил все относящееся к прокси из gradle.properties (4 вписанные ранее строки). Задавал автоматическую настроил прокси-сервера и отключал прокси, и теперь при загрузке проекта всплывает ошибка **Plugin was not found in any of the following sources:**, которая была у меня раньше при медленном интернете. Ошибка подробно описана тут - [Ошибка "Plugin was not found" при медленном интернете](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1516312/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-plugin-was-not-found-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5)

С целью устранения ошибки **Plugin was not found** решил добавить в библиотеку файл *com.android.application*. Для скачивания файла com.android.application с расширением jar или zip из репозитория Гугла  перешел по адресу:  https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.0.0, но на этой странице не вижу файла `com.android.application-8.0.0.jar` или `com.android.application-8.0.0.zip`. Как  в репозитарии найти один из этих файлов?

Comment: как же нет, когда есть. Раскрыть надо. И если прикладываете скриншот в вопрос. то обрезайте его до нужного фрагмента, никого не интересует весь экран.

Comment: вы наугад все делаете? Почему no proxy, если из вопроса и из предыдущих действий следует, что прокси все же есть?

Comment: Не наугад. Я выполнил вашу рекомендацию. Повторюсь, я пытался установить  прокси, но у меня не получилось, поскольку не знаю номера порта.,  С номером 80 -  не прошло. @Эникейщик

Comment: мои рекомендации - сделать правильные настройки, а не поставить чекбокс no proxy.

Comment: Gradle выдает "Plugin was not found" как при медленном интернете, так и [при отсутствующем интернете](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1518990). Не совсем понял из вашего вопроса (из предыдущего вопроса это тоже не ясно), для чего изначально вам понадобился прокси? Без прокси были какие-то проблемы?

Comment: Vadik Sirekanyan, моей начальной целью было подключение к высокоскоростному интернету соседа, но при подключении не было туннелирования.  Дальше делал то, что было в ответе и комментах - подключал прокси, отключал проксси. пока не вышел на ошибку  "Plugin was not found". Кстати,  загрузил в АС ваш демо-проект с ГитХаба. Отдельное спасибо за проект. Ошибка та же - "Plugin was not found". @Vadik Sirekanyan

Comment: Как вы подключаетесь к интернету соседа? Ваш сосед выступает в качестве прокси-сервера, правильно я понял? Предполагаю, что в таком случае вопрос не по android-studio, а про правильную организацию сети. Уверены ли в том, что настройки прокси, которые вы указываете -- рабочие?

Comment: В правильных настройках прокси я уверен, поскольку при настройке поставил опцию УСТАНОВИТЬ АВТОМАТИЧЕСКИ.  @Vadik Sirekanyan

Comment: А можете для дополнительной проверки работоспособности прокси настроить эти прокси в каком-либо браузере? В каждом браузере (chrome, firefox и др.) в настроках можно указать прокси. Если браузер с прокси будет работать, то мы поймем, что проблема действительно с Android Studio, а не с прокси. И еще, скажите, помог ли вам [ответ Эникейщика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1520063)?

Comment: Проверка прокси - это не та ветвь, по которой я готов идти. И с качественным и некачественным интернетом та же ошибка "Plugin was not found".  Я подправил вопрос. Почитайте, пожалуйста, и помогите!

Comment: Если у вас качественный интернет, то отключите прокси и наслаждайтесь. Если вам нужен по какой-то причине прокси (я пока так и не понял зачем он вам), то убедитесь каким-либо другим способом, что он работает, чтобы уже потом возиться с более сложным комбайном Android Studio. Отреагируйте как-нибудь на [ответ Эникейщика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1520063), этот ответ вам не подошел? Почему? Напишите прямо в комментарии **под его ответом**.

Answer (score 1):

Удали все относящееся к прокси из `gradle.properties` и сделай правильные настройки в `File` | `Settings` | `Appearance & Behavior` | `System Settings` | `HTTP Proxy`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Эникейщик, спасибо за помощь. К сожалению, и с прокси и без него я  вышел на свою старую проблему **Plugin was not found**, с которой мучаюсь уже давно и пытаюсь решить методом перебора вариантов.  @Vadik Sirekanyan